# Bash script, when executable requires 2 arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

If an "file.exe" only need one number as argument, I can create a .sh file (bash script) with:

```
#!/bin/bash
($1) | ./file.exe
```

But this program ask 2 arguments in two different moments: first a number and then a string:

```
user@machine:/home/user> ./file.exe
<Please enter a number>
<Please enter a name>
```

So I can't just write the .sh file with

```
#!/bin/bash
($1 $2) | ./file.exe
```

How can I create this sh file?

Comment: well, those aren't arguments (those are passed on the command line).  to do interactive stuff like this, look at using `expect` and `send`

Comment: Those are **inputs**, not arguments. Arguments would be `./file.exe 123 'Joe'`.

Comment: Do any of the current answers solve your problem? If so, please indicate one by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear how you are attempting to pass the single argument in your first example, but it sounds like you want to pre-supply two arguments to a process that reads its input from stdin.

Here are two variations on the same idea of providing input to an arbitrary program:

```
(printf "%s\n" "value 1"; date) | ./file.exe

printf "%s\n%s\n" "value 1" "value two" | ./file.exe
```

In the first example, we use a subshell to group the two separate commands together before piping their output as input to file.exe. This example demonstrates that the commands could be anything that provide (the appropriate) output for file.exe to consume.

In the second example, we use a single printf statement with two values, separated and terminated with newline characters. This example could be extended to provide dynamic input to the printf statement itself:

```
printf "%s\n%s\n" "$(date)" "$(uptime)" | ./file.exe
```

Or, as Gilles pointed out in the comments, break out of the `printf` box and simply pipe the commands' outputs directly:

```
{ date; uptime; } | ./file.exe
```

Comment: That last example would be much clearer as `{ date; uptime; } | ./file.exe` (or variants such as using a function) though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ./file.exe
expect "<Please enter a number>"
send "123\n"
expect "<Please enter a name>"
send "Joe Bloggs\n"
interact
```